# How to I convert a text file with google translate api?

Tags: c#, api, google-translate

I want to convert a csv file with google translate api, but I can only translate the text in the code.

How can I convert the text file I received from outside in C#.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        string text = "Example text";

        //key path
        string credential_path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + 
        @"App_Start\enkup-b1783076ded2.json";


        //key to api connection          
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
        "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", credential_path);
        TranslationClient client = TranslationClient.Create();


        string ceviri_sonuc = client.TranslateText(text, "en", 
        "de").TranslatedText;

        return View();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What happens whrn you pass the contents of the CSV file to the translation service?

Comment: how can i pass to translate all file?

Comment: Well, you read the contents as a string and pass it to the service?

Comment: I want to convert the xml file to csv, but at the same time I want to translate the xml contents into English. so I want to get a translated csv. thanks